# All Firefox Traffic routing through SOCKS-Proxy?

Tags: firefox, browser, web, socks-proxy, webrtc

I would like to route all my Firefox-browsers traffic through a proxy server. I already setup a Dante-Proxy (SOCKS) and configured the paramters in about:config to use it:

```
"network.proxy.type": 1
"network.proxy.socks": "10.192.65.129"
"network.proxy.socks_port": 1080
"network.proxy.socks_remote_dns": True
"network.proxy.socks_version": 5
```

This seems to work, but now I'm wondering if this covers all the traffic the browser creates. DNS should be fine (because of the remote_dns-option), but how about calls from WebRTC or other things that I might not know. Is there anything that could get through this setup without routing over the SOCKS-Proxy? Are there countermeasures?